# Display text as hyperlink in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, hyperlink, styling

```
<mx:VBox id="paSenate" label="PA Senate" width="100%" verticalGap="0">
            <mx:HBox>
                <mx:Label text="PA Senate" fontWeight="bold"></mx:Label>
                <mx:Label id="paSenateConf" text="" />
            </mx:HBox>
            <mx:Label id="paSenateNameLabel" text="" paddingLeft="5"/>
            <mx:Label id="paSenateCountyLabel" text="" paddingLeft="5"/>
            <mx:Label id="paSenateURLLabel" text="" paddingLeft="5"/>
        </mx:VBox>
```

The code I have above displays results based on an address search. All the information being displayed is coming from either database or a web service. Including the web address for Senate and House members. The website is coming back as a string. Right now it is just simply being passed into the text field of paSenateURLLabel. I need to change it somehow to a hyperlink so it's clickable. This is being done in Flex 3.5. Not entirely sure how I would go about doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flex 3 has a [LinkButton](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/LinkButton.html) component that will do this. (Note, if you were using Flex 4 you would just make text based skin for a `Button` or use TLF text which has hyperlink functionality.)

```
<mx:LinkButton label="I'm a link" click="linkClickhandler()" />
```

Comment: I was hoping to not do a link button but It doesn't look like I have many options.

Comment: Another option would be to use a Label, and add mouse handlers to it: `<mx:Label text="link" mouseOver="setStyle('textDecoration', 'underline')" mouseOut="setStyle('textDecoration', 'none')" click="onLinkClick()"/>` If necessary, you could add other things that the LinkButton automatically does (ability to receive focus/accept keyboard input, a mouse down state, etc.).