# How do I get the LinkButton in flex to underline on mouse over

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, linkbutton

I am new to using flex. I have a linkButton and I need it to underline when I hover the mouse over. I think it can be done by setstyle() but I don't know the syntax and how it works. I looked around but it quite find anything useful related to this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to use is:

```
buttonObject.setStyle("property", "value");
```

A complete example:

```
<fx:Script> 
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        protected function linkbutton1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show('LinkButton selected!');
        }

        protected function linkbutton1_mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            btn.setStyle("textDecoration", "underline");
        }

        protected function linkbutton1_mouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            btn.setStyle("textDecoration", "none");

        }

    ]]>

</fx:Script>

<mx:LinkButton id="btn" label="LinkButton control" color="#0000FF" fontWeight="bold" rollOverColor="#FFFFFF"
       mouseOver="linkbutton1_mouseOverHandler(event)"
       mouseOut="linkbutton1_mouseOutHandler(event)"
       click="linkbutton1_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

See more at [Display text as hyperlink in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307464/display-text-as-hyperlink-in-flex) and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/LinkButton.html